# Sort an array with values of integer

Tags: arithmetic, sorting

There is an array of integer values to be sorted.During the sorting process, the places of two numbers can be interchanged. Each interchange has a cost, which is the sum of the two numbers involved.

You must write a program that determines the minimal cost to sort the sequence of numbers.

Comment: First of all please read the [faq](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq). Your puzzle should have an objective primary winning criterion. Have a look around to see many well-specified questions. You may also read the comments below your last puzzle as those also address the same questions.

Comment: We _*must*_? You should change site...

Comment: Are the integers equally distributed, or normal distributed, or somehow else? How many of them and how big? Do you have some sample input, something like `for i in {1..100}; do echo $((RANDOM%256)); done` for example.

Comment: They are not equally distrubuted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Scala:

```
def minimalCostToSortArray (daArray: Array[Int]) = 0
```

Why is the cost always zero? Because I don't change numbers at all:

```
def arrsort (a: Array[Int], pos:Int = 0): Array[Int] = {
  if (pos >= a.length -1) a else { 
    if (a(pos) > a(pos+1)) {
      val diff = a(pos) - a(pos+1)
      a (pos) -= diff
      a (pos+1) += diff
      arrsort (a)
    } else arrsort (a, pos+1) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: For the challenge to make sense at all, I'd interpret it as saying that the _only_ operation we're allowed to use to modify the array is swapping two numbers. Still, +1 for thinking outside the box (and -1 for cheating, which leaves the total at ±0).

Comment: I read `... the places can be interchanged` as optional, but more so, as badly prepared question. I understand my answer more as a criticism on a badly prepared question.